# Extract headers from message using spring-rabbit without declaring queues in annotation

Tags: java, rabbitmq, messaging, spring-rabbit

Now I can do like this:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = {ENTITY_KEY + "-snapshots",  ENTITY_KEY + "-updates"})
public void handleMessage(ProviderOddsOffer offer, @Header("update_type") Long updateType) {
    ...
}
```

Can I do it without declaring queues in annotation itself?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean; the listener has to be configured to consume from some queue.

Comment: exactly but this queue might not be defined statically like in this case, I want to have ability to bind this consumer to any queue I want, not using the annotation, because annotation means I know the name of the queue at compile time, and I maybe don't know it.

Comment: You can use a property placeholder `${...}` or a SpEL expression `#{...}` for the queue name(s); they will be resolved during bean initialization.

Comment: yes, thank you, should I close the question or you will post the answer?

Comment: Done; moved my comments to an answer.

Comment: Can you suggest, how can I access the property or method that is supposed to handle messages. I want to do something like this "#{this.otherBean.getQueueName()}", can I do something like this?

Comment: `#{otherBean.getQueueName()}` should work ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean; the listener has to be configured to consume from some queue, or queues.

If you that mean you wish to externalize the queue name(s) rather than hard-coding in java, you can use a property placeholder ${...} or a SpEL expression #{...} for the queue name(s); they will be resolved during bean initialization.